# Trigger Operation Recursion Flag not working as expected

Tags: apex, trigger

I have the following trigger framework that uses the variable blockedObjectIdsByOperation to see if we have ran the trigger operation within the execution context.

```
public class ContactTriggerHandler 
{

    static Set<TriggerOperation> blockedObjectIdsByOperation = new Set<TriggerOperation>();

    public Integer triggerSize = 0;
    public Boolean triggerIsExecuting = false;

    public ContactTriggerHandler(Boolean isExecuting , Integer size) 
    {
        triggerIsExecuting = isExecuting;
        triggerSize = size;
    }

    public void OnBeforeInsert(List<Contact> newContacts, TriggerOperation operation)
    {  

        ContactPersonas.run(newContacts);

    }
    public void OnBeforeUpdate( List<Contact> newContacts, List<Contact> oldContacts, Map<ID, Contact> newContactMap , Map<ID, Contact> oldContactMap, TriggerOperation operationType )
    {
        if(blockedObjectIdsByOperation.contains(operationType))
        {
            return ;
        }
        else 
        {
            blockedObjectIdsByOperation.add(operationType);
            ContactPersonas.run(newContacts, oldContactMap);




        }
    }
}
```

What I am finding is that the blockedObjectIdsByOperation is persisting across each of my updates in the test class.

```
public someTestClass    {
        for(Contact con: contacts)
            {
                con.title = 'CFO';
            }

            update contacts;


            for(Contact con: contacts)
            {
                con.title = 'AR Manager';
            }

            update contacts;


            for(Contact con: contacts)
            {
                con.title = 'Operations VP';
            }

            update contacts;


            for(Contact con: contacts)
            {
                con.title = 'President';
            }

            update contacts;

        }
```

Shouldn't this flag reset with each new update call?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, static variables reset only when the transaction finishes, not after every DML operation. This is why using this "recursion blocking" technique is often a Bad Idea. The only time you should use this technique is to block actual recursion. Some people call the "second trigger" from workflow field updates a "recursion", but it's not. It's a one-time repeat. Recursion is what happens when you do something like this:

```
trigger trigger1 on Account (after update) {
  update [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :Trigger.new];
}

trigger trigger2 on Contact (after update) {
  update [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :Trigger.new)];
}
```

As you can see, the contacts update the accounts, which update the contacts, *recursively*. To stop this, you add recursion blocking there:

```
trigger trigger1 on Account (after update) {
  if(GlobalFlags.stopAccountTrigger) 
    return;
  GlobalFlags.stopAccountTrigger = true;
  update [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE AccountId = :Trigger.new];
  GlobalFlags.stopAccountTrigger = false;
}

trigger trigger2 on Contact (after update) {
  if(GlobalFlags.stopContactTrigger) 
    return;
  GlobalFlags.stopContactTrigger = true;
  update [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Id IN (SELECT AccountId FROM Contact WHERE Id = :Trigger.new)];
  GlobalFlags.stopContactTrigger = false;
}
```

Here, we implement two public static Boolean variables to stop the trigger from going into infinite recursion. Note that we always reset the variable at the end of the trigger; we want future updates to work.

You need to remember to reset the variable at the end of the trigger context so that it will work correctly in all cases, such as when you're updating more than 200 records (trigger batch size), or for controller operations that may involve several DML operations on the same object, etc.

The **only** time you should **ever** use recursion blocking is if you specifically get an exception that states "Trigger depth limit exceeded", **and** you have no better way to resolve the error than to use recursion blocking. Often, simply checking to see if a field has changed, or if the record needs to be updated can be just as effective as recursion blocking code.